# Perl, counting words with special characters

Tags: regex, perl

I need to count number of words including special characters like % ,$ in a particular section of an XML document.

I need to write this in Perl script using regular expressions.

Anyone has any suggestions on where I can start to look for more info as this is my first perl script.

1. I need help with isolating the section and its data.
2. I will probably use that data to pass to a subroutine to count words.

```
name
desc
address
line1
line2
line3
```

In the example above, I need to capture address and all the lines inside it and build a string that is going to be counted.

Comment: Which part do you need help with first? Reading the XML or counting the words? What have you tried so far? When is your homework due?

Comment: What do you consider as special character? Is it anything not alphanumerics + '_'? And are you able to isolate that `particular section of an XML document` already or do you need Perl to perform that bit programmatically? If can edit your question to make it more specific, it will help.

Comment: I need help to capture a particular section in the xml i.e.
<xml>
<name> </name>
<desc> </desc>
<address> <line1></line1><line2> </line2><line3></line3></address>
</xml>

in the example above, i need to capture address and all the lines inside it.

Comment: Mind posting a sample snippet of the raw XML code section, and the desired result after you process it?

Comment: I know you edited your question - but it's so poorly worded that I don't even know how to get started in helping you. Again, if you could post a sample section of the XML code you want to tackle and the desired end result, we may get somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
my $counter = 0;
$counter++ while ($string =~ m/[\S]+/g);
```

This will give you the count of words (groups of characters in between whitespace) and will include special characters such as %, $ if they are separated by whitespace from other words.

Answer (score 4):

Aha.  You want to parse XML.  Use an XML parser, for example
XML::Twig.  [Here](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2001/03/21/xmltwig.html)
is an introduction.

Answer (score -1):

Providing you have the text in a string already, you can try this:

```
my $counter = 0;
my @words = split " ", $string;
for my $word (@words) {
    $counter++ if ($word =~ /\W/);
}
print $counter;
```